# Find kth smallest element in Java array with recursion, no imports, and in one method

Tags: java, recursion, methods

First, let me verify that I know topics like this exist, but I found my case unique. Firstly, all of my code is, and has to, in one method (not that it matters much, but I find it makes it harder to keep an overview) as per my professors odd request.

Secondly, the method has to use recursion (which is new to me, so I suspect this is where I fall of).

Thirdly, the method has to take an array, a key (which is the kth **smallest** number), and two integers, first and last.

Fourthly, the pivot item always has to be the first element of the array. Which I gave the value "p", as you'll see in the code.

So in this one method, I have to sort and find the key (which as mentioned is the kth number the method takes as argument) provided for any key.

I felt this was specific enough to warrant its own question, so here I am.

Firstly, the following are the numbers I gave myself to work with (which I found randomly online from some other guy trying to explain a similar, but not equal problem):

```
    int[] b = { 42, 92, 31, 73, 46, 11, 29, 53, 64, 4 };
```

That being said, here is the line I've been using to test the method thus far.

```
    System.out.println(findNth(b, 6, 0, b.length));
```

Note that every number 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 have all worked in returning the lowest, second lowest, third lowest, etc etc value perfectly, and I really thought I had it for a while.

I crashed at 6 and after a few hours of not getting anywhere, I decided to plea for help.

So here's the monster-long method I've made thus far:

```
    static public int findNth(int[] t, int key, int first, int last) {


    int p = t[0];

    int smallerSize = 0;
    int largerSize = 0;

    int[] smallerTab;
    int[] largerTab;

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        if (t[i] < p) {
            smallerSize++;
        } else {
            largerSize++;
        }
    }

    smallerTab = new int[smallerSize];
    largerTab = new int[largerSize - 1];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < smallerTab.length) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
            if (t[j] < p) {
                smallerTab[i] = t[j];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    int y = 0;
    while (y < largerTab.length) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
            if (t[j] > p) {
                largerTab[y] = t[j];
                y++;
            }
        }
    }

    int c = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < t.length; a++) {
        if (a < smallerTab.length) {
            t[a] = smallerTab[a];
        }
        if (a == smallerTab.length) {
            t[a] = p;
        }
        if (a > smallerTab.length) {
            t[a] = largerTab[c];
            c++;
        }
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int d = 0; d < t.length; d++) {
        if (t[d] == p) {
            index = d;
        }
    }

    if (key < index - first + 1) {
        return findNth(smallerTab, key, 0, smallerTab.length - 1);
    }

    else if ((key == index - first + 1) || index == 0) {
        return p;
    }

    else {
        return findNth(largerTab, (key - (index - first + 1)), index + 1,
                largerTab.length);
    }

}
```

I humbly request the aid of any minds brighter than mine to help me overcome this problem.

An explanation of where my mistake is, would be preferred, but any advice or code to my predicament would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean the kth `smallest` element?

Comment: Are you sorting the array based on a partition?

Comment: @Prince Yes, was I not clear on that? I'll update the question!

Comment: @NicRobertson Yes, I am forced to use the first object of the array. Good of you to point out, as I failed to mention it. Question updated.

Comment: @ViRALiC so you are implementing Quicksort then? If so there are no shortages of examples both here and elsewhere on the web

Comment: @NicRobertson Ah yes, no doubt. And yeah, Quicksort is in the picture. Sadly none of the other resources on the web gave me insight enough to know how to solve my problem, so I was hoping if I showed my problem to someone I could get some manual help. Someone to point me at what I'm doing wrong, perhaps.

Comment: This is an `Order Statistics` problem. Like quicksort algorithm, select a random pivot and partition the array.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/ this is a good implementation of quicksort in java which should help you out. As you can see it is better to sort in place rather than create extra arrays for each side of the partition

Comment: @NicRobertson I see why you'd think that, and while the example provided certainly covers Quicksort, I am not sure its my partitioning which is the problem... I think it's more the recursive aspect that's crashing my method.